# Find the Probability density function of a mean random variable

Tags: probability, density-function

lets say $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n}$ are simple random samples with the PDF: $f_{\theta}(y)=\theta y^{\theta - 1} \mathbb{I}(0 \le y \le 1) $
How can I find the PDF of $\bar{Y}$? is it even possible?

Comment: $f(x)=tx^{t-1}$? Shouldn't it be $f(y)=ty^{t-1}$

Comment: @IshraaqParvez my mistake

Comment: Is domain of your pdf $y \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: @Joitandr Yes it is

Comment: Please do not cross-post across sites.